# Remove a file just before shutdown/reboot

Tags: 12.04

I added the following content in `/etc/init.d/reboot` script:

```
FILE="/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules"
rm $FILE
```

This did not work, since it complained when I restarted the system:

```
rm: cannot remove `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules': Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use /etc/rc.local for your customization of reboot process.

Among the hooks can be used to include custom code in various places in the rc.* init [scripts](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Initscripts): shutdown_start   At the beginning of rc.shutdown

If it says Read-only file system, you don't have sufficient permission to remove the file.

By the way, explain your main objective, maybe folks can help you with a better approach.

Comment: I use the same OS image on different machines, which results in the rules files having a bunch of `eth*` entries. I only want `eth0` in there.

Comment: There should not be a permissions issue since the init script is ran as root.

Comment: Adding the command in `/etc/rc.local` worked well enough, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the file writable. To do this use the following command:

```
sudo chmod +w 'name of your file'
```

Comment: it is already writable